# iOS- How to fix retain cycles that come from modal segues in XCode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-management, memory-leaks

I ran the allocations instruments and I definitely have a retain cycle, the stairs-like graph is a dead giveaway. However, I'm new to iOS programming and have no idea how to fix my retain cycle issue even after sifting through the internet for documentation. To my knowledge there are some strong references that are preventing unused memory from being deallocated in my ARC project. The app is a simple soundboard but has a lot of content, which is why I haven't had to deal with this issue before. Memory is a real problem now. For ViewController.m I have

```
@import GoogleMobileAds;

#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController () <GADInterstitialDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>
{
    AVAudioPlayer *_audioPlayer;
}
@property(nonatomic, strong) GADInterstitial *interstitial;

@end
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self createAndLoadInterstitial];

    BannerManager *sharedManager = [BannerManager sharedManager];
    GADBannerView* bView = [sharedManager setupBannerAds:self.view];
    bView.delegate = self;
    bView.rootViewController = self;

    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    [bView loadRequest:request];
}

- (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)bannerView {
    NSLog(@"adViewDidReceiveAd: %@", bannerView.adNetworkClassName);
}


int counter = 0;

#pragma Interstitial button actions

- (IBAction)playAgain:(id)sender {

    if (counter % 15 == 0) {
        if (self.interstitial.isReady) {
            [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
        } else {

        }
    }

    counter++;
}

- (void)createAndLoadInterstitial {
    self.interstitial =
    [[GADInterstitial alloc] initWithAdUnitID:@"mygoogleidgoeshere"];
    self.interstitial.delegate = self;

    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];

    [self.interstitial loadRequest:request];
}


#pragma mark GADInterstitialDelegate implementation

- (void)interstitial:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial
didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error {
    NSLog(@"interstitialDidFailToReceiveAdWithError: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

- (void)interstitialDidDismissScreen:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial {
    NSLog(@"interstitialDidDismissScreen");
    [self createAndLoadInterstitial];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}





- (IBAction)areyoufinishedyet:(id)sender {

    soundFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                        pathForResource:@"areyoufinishedyet"
                                        ofType:@"mp3"]];

    sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFile error:nil];
    sound.delegate = self;
    [sound play];

}

- (IBAction)areyoulooking:(id)sender {

    soundFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                        pathForResource:@"areyoulooking"
                                        ofType:@"mp3"]];

    sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFile error:nil];
    sound.delegate = self;
    [sound play];
}

- (IBAction)blueeyes:(id)sender {

    soundFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                        pathForResource:@"blueeyes"
                                        ofType:@"mp3"]];

    sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFile error:nil];
    sound.delegate = self;
    [sound play];
}

- (IBAction)crosshairs:(id)sender {

    soundFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                        pathForResource:@"crosshairs"
                                        ofType:@"mp3"]];

    sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFile error:nil];
    sound.delegate = self;
    [sound play];
}

- (IBAction)doyoumind:(id)sender {

    soundFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                        pathForResource:@"doyoumind"
                                        ofType:@"mp3"]];

    sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFile error:nil];
    sound.delegate = self;
    [sound play];
}

- (IBAction)dontblink:(id)sender {

    soundFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                        pathForResource:@"dontblink"
                                        ofType:@"mp3"]];

    sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFile error:nil];
    sound.delegate = self;
    [sound play];
}

- (IBAction)growontrees:(id)sender {

    soundFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                        pathForResource:@"growontrees"
                                        ofType:@"mp3"]];

    sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFile error:nil];
    sound.delegate = self;
    [sound play];
}

- (IBAction)iamagenius:(id)sender {

    soundFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                        pathForResource:@"iamagenius"
                                        ofType:@"mp3"]];

    sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFile error:nil];
    sound.delegate = self;
    [sound play];}

- (IBAction)imarealboy:(id)sender {

    soundFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                        pathForResource:@"imarealboy"
                                        ofType:@"mp3"]];

    sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFile error:nil];
    sound.delegate = self;
    [sound play];
}

- (IBAction)importantbusiness:(id)sender {

    soundFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                        pathForResource:@"importantbusiness"
                                        ofType:@"mp3"]];

    sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFile error:nil];
    sound.delegate = self;
    [sound play];
}

- (IBAction)inmyeye:(id)sender {

    soundFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                        pathForResource:@"inmyeye"
                                        ofType:@"mp3"]];

    sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFile error:nil];
    sound.delegate = self;
    [sound play];
}

- (IBAction)justblinked:(id)sender {

    soundFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                        pathForResource:@"justblinked"
                                        ofType:@"mp3"]];

    sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFile error:nil];
    sound.delegate = self;
    [sound play];
}

- (IBAction)mustyoureally:(id)sender {

    soundFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                        pathForResource:@"mustyoureally"
                                        ofType:@"mp3"]];

    sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFile error:nil];
    sound.delegate = self;
    [sound play];
}

- (IBAction)nottheenemy:(id)sender {

    soundFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                        pathForResource:@"nottheenemy"
                                        ofType:@"mp3"]];

    sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFile error:nil];
    sound.delegate = self;
    [sound play];
}

- (IBAction)oddlyenough:(id)sender {

    soundFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                        pathForResource:@"oddlyenough"
                                        ofType:@"mp3"]];

    sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFile error:nil];
    sound.delegate = self;
    [sound play];}

- (IBAction)staringcontest:(id)sender {

    soundFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                        pathForResource:@"staringcontest"
                                        ofType:@"mp3"]];

    sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFile error:nil];
    sound.delegate = self;
    [sound play];
}

- (IBAction)youreaklutz:(id)sender {

    soundFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                        pathForResource:@"youreaklutz"
                                        ofType:@"mp3"]];

    sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFile error:nil];
    sound.delegate = self;
    [sound play];}

- (IBAction)youreamoron:(id)sender {

    soundFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                        pathForResource:@"youreamoron"
                                        ofType:@"mp3"]];

    sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFile error:nil];
    sound.delegate = self;
    [sound play];}

- (IBAction)yourepissingmeoff:(id)sender {

    soundFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                        pathForResource:@"yourepissingmeoff"
                                        ofType:@"mp3"]];

    sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFile error:nil];
    sound.delegate = self;
    [sound play];}

- (IBAction)challengeme:(id)sender {

    soundFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                        pathForResource:@"challengeme"
                                        ofType:@"mp3"]];

    sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFile error:nil];
    sound.delegate = self;
    [sound play];}

- (IBAction)forerunners:(id)sender {

    soundFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                        pathForResource:@"forerunners"
                                        ofType:@"mp3"]];

    sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFile error:nil];
    sound.delegate = self;
    [sound play];}
```

and for Viewcontroller.h I have

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "BannerManager.h"
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@import GoogleMobileAds;

@interface ViewController: UIViewController<GADBannerViewDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate>  {
    NSURL *soundFile;
    AVAudioPlayer *sound;
}

//343 GUILTY SPARK
- (IBAction)areyoufinishedyet:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)areyoulooking:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)blueeyes:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)crosshairs:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)doyoumind:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)dontblink:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)growontrees:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)iamagenius:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)imarealboy:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)importantbusiness:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)inmyeye:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)justblinked:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)mustyoureally:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)nottheenemy:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)oddlyenough:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)staringcontest:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)youreaklutz:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)youreamoron:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)yourepissingmeoff:(id)sender;

//ARBITER
- (IBAction)challengeme:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)forerunners:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)halospurpose:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)imgoingtocutit:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)imprepared:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)readytofight:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)sacredrings:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)saveyouranger:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)youshotmefoo:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)tararusstop:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)trymypatience:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)whatyouwant:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)arbiterdo:(id)sender;

//BRUTES
- (IBAction)adaysrations:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)atinymorsel:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)bastardelite:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)boilinyourpot:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)cannedmeat:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)cannotescape:(id)sender;
```

this is only part of the code because the rest is pretty huge, and is basically the same line of code over and over with minor changes to the files it references. My question is how in the world do I fix retain cycles? Is it something to do with my modal transitions? Because this is what's causing crazy memory allocation in instruments and crashes on my native iOS device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like you don't have a retain cycle, exactly. It sounds like you are presenting a never-ending series of view controllers on top of other view controllers.

Using a modal present or a navigation controller push has a similar effect: The previous view controller gets covered with a new one but does not get freed.

You didn't post any of the code that shows how you navigate from view controller to view controller, so it's hard to tell what you're doing exactly.

If you want to go from view controller A to view controller B to view controller C, then back to A, you need to present from A to B, then from B to C, but dismiss in order to get back, not present a new copy of view controller A.

Comment: Okay, that would make sense as well. My ViewControllers are connected in the storyboard (as in I just clicked and dragged modal connections from the buttons to ViewControllers). How would I go about doing what you suggested, where it's A to B and B to C, or write some code that unloads the last ViewController?

Comment: Never use a modal segue to go back. You want to either use an unwind segue, or write an IBAction method that calls dismissViewController:animated:completion: through code.

Comment: Thank you for this advice. I'll go make the changes to my app and come back if I have any more questions.